# Can an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$ in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ ($k\ge 1$) be dense in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M$ be a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$ ($k\ge 1$); then, can $M$ be dense in $\mathbb R^{n+k}$?

I have no idea how to proceed. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by ``in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$"? Do you mean an open submanifold, or an embedded submanifold?

Comment: It depends what "in" means here. If we require that $M$ be embedded in $\Bbb R^{n + k}$, the answer is no; if we only require that $M$ be immersed, the answer is yes (consider $M = \Bbb Q$, so that $n = 0$, and $k = 1$).

Comment: @Travis : I mean embedded ..

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is embedded in $\Bbb R^{n+k}$ then $M$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^{n+k}$.

If $k=0$, then the only submanifolds of the same dimension as the surrounding manifold are its open subsets. It follows that $M$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$ if and only if it is a dense open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. There are many examples of such subsets: just remove a finite number of points, or linear subspaces of dimension $\le n-1$, from $\Bbb R^n$.

If $k \ge 1$ then pick an arbitrary point $p \in M$. Since $M$ is a submanifold in $\Bbb R^{n+k}$, there exists an open subset $U \subseteq \Bbb R^{n+k}$ around $p$, an open subset $V \subseteq \Bbb R ^{n+k}$, and a diffeomorphism $f : U \to V$, such that $f (M \cap U) = V \cap (\Bbb R^n \times \{0_k\})$, with $0_k$ being the $0$ vector in $\Bbb R^k$. (Essentially, this tells that, modulo a diffeomorphism, every $n$ - dimensional submanifold is locally an $n$ - dimensional linear subspace.)

Pick now a point $q \in V \setminus \Big( V \cap (\Bbb R^n \times \{0_k\}) \Big)$. Since $V$ is open, you may find a small enough open subset $W$ around $q$ such that $W \cap \Big( V \cap (\Bbb R^n \times \{0_k\}) \Big) = \emptyset$. Now, the core fact: $f^{-1} (W)$ is open (because $f$ is a diffeomorphism) and, by construction, $f^{-1} (W) \cap M = \emptyset$. So, you have found an open subset of $\Bbb R^{n+k}$ that does not intersect $M$. But one definition of topological density is: $M$ is dense if and only if it intersects every open subset. This shows that $M$ is not dense in $\Bbb R^{n+k}$.